# Python 'object' type and inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, object

In Python I can define a class 'foo' in the following ways:

```
class foo:
    pass
```

or

```
class foo(object):
    pass
```

What is the difference?  I have tried to use the function issubclass(foo, object) to see if it returns True for both class definitions.  It does not.

```
IDLE 2.6.3      
>>> class foo:
        pass

>>> issubclass(foo, object)
False
>>> class foo(object):
        pass

>>> issubclass(foo, object)
True
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inheriting from `object` makes a class a "new-style class".  There is a discussion of old-style vs. new-style here: [[What is the difference between old style and new style classes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python)

As @CrazyJugglerDrummer commented below, in Python 3 all classes are "new-style" classes.  In Python 3, the following two declarations are exactly equivalent:

```
class A(object):
    pass

class A:
    pass
```

Comment: addition: in py 3, everything's automatically a new style class

Answer (score 2):

The first creates an "old-style" class, which are deprecated and have been removed in Python 3. You should not use it in Python 2.x. See the documentation for the [Python data model](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes).

Answer (score 2):

*Old style* and *new style* objects... they have sightly different behaviours, for example in the constructors, or in the method resolution order in multiple inheritance.