# In Python, what is the difference between "class name(object):" and "class name():"

Tags: python, object

What is the difference between the two classes below? Do you have some related information about this case? Thank you very much.

```
class test(object):
  def __init__(self, name):
     print name

class test():
  def __init__(self, name):
     print name
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python 'object' type and inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540975/python-object-type-and-inheritance)

Comment: The `()` is unnecessary, as a matter of fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python 2.x, the class that inherits from `object` will be a new-style class, while the other won't, while in python 3.x there'll be both new-style.

However, the differences between new and old are rather advanced, (for example, attribute search order) so a beginner shouldn't be too concerned about the incompatibilities.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python) answer for more information if you're interested, but it's rather a thing for library developers etc.

Answer (score 4):

Mhmm ... this wiki-page explains the differences very illustratively: http://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass

And I saw some answeres with the information, that Old-(Classic)-Style and New-Style classes are *the same* in py3 -> that's not correct:

> [image] *Old-style classes **are removed** in Python 3, leaving only the semantics of new-style classes*

Besides this, the *New-Style classes* are quite available since Python 2.2. Up to 2.1 we have had to use the Classic style [-> see here](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.2.html)

**Short summary about the differences/infos could be:**

- New-Style classes are available since Python 2.2
- New-Style classes can use descriptors - Old Style classes cannot
- New Style classes can subclass most built-in types - Old Style classes cannot
- New Style classes supports a new meta-model (which affects e.g. the behaviour of the [`type()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type) built-in massively)
- Old-Style classes will find an attribute on an instance before it looks in the hierarchy - New-Style classes will let the class definition win if it is a writeable descriptor
- Old-Style classes has been removed in Python 3

But in most way the introduction of the New-style classes has been affected within the comming up of python's **Descriptors** [--> read more here](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html).

Answer (score -3):

In this case, none, because the first explicitly inherits from object as a base class, while the second inherits from object implicitly.

Comment: There is a difference. Check `test.__mro__` for the first class. The second class throws an `AttributeError`.